# Frequently push data to web server (.net)

Tags: .net, signalr, push

In one of our application, we need to collect data from devices (like sensor, boiler etc) and push it to our web application (hosted on internet). Frequency of data is going to be high (may be per 5 seconds).

I was searching for creating some persistent connection (rather than creating http connection) between web server (on internet) and window service (running on client).

I have not browsed though but signalR could be used here (over websockets). Could you please provide some insight on this topic.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [self-hosted](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host) option since you are running a windows service, this would be the most suitable option.

Basically, you will be creating an endpoint url to which all your clients will then hook into. Once the clients are registered to the hub, SignalR would be able to push data to the clients based on any of your events firing off (boiler sensor etc).

Start of simply by just creating a timer to push some messages. Then, remove the timer and re-factor to add in your events from the boilers etc.

Comment: You are proposing to host signalR on client application(window service) and web application will be it's client? I am not able to understand. Web application work in some request context. How it can be client?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your use case correctly. You have a set of sensor data that needs to be fed into your web site, correct? Are you also saying you have multiple clients (windows services) that collect the data? If so, then you would then you are correct, you would need to create the hub in the website and then get your clients (windows services) to send the messages to the website (hub) which then pushes all the message to the other clients. Or, am I totally on the wrong path? Please let me know and I will then update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already decided that you want to use WebSockets for this requirement then-

Have a SignalR Hub http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr and host it inside your web Application.
Let all the windows service clients register to it and call the methods on Hub class (using Hub proxy). 
It looks like that you don't need the communication back from web application to clients, but this option will always be available for you to use it for future extensibility .